# Passport number change upon print error correction?

Tags: visas, passports, us-citizens

I just noticed that they messed up my place of birth and I need to have that corrected.

My issue is that I have to apply (quickly) for a business visa to India but now it seems I'll have to wait until I get the correction back.

Will my passport number change if it's a print error that they need to correct or will it stay the same and I can apply for my visa while I wait for my corrected passport to return?

Comment: From which country?

Comment: United States..

Comment: Based on [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69321/will-my-passport-number-change-when-i-renew-it), it should be an international standard that you get a new passport number anytime the physical document changes.

Comment: Indian Passports, if you notice a clerical error from them (& you filled the forms right, they messed up), if you submit back within a week, they keep the same number, no fees.